# How to add attachments to an email from a string list with LINQ C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have to add Email Attachments to a MailMessage, I did it with a foreach but I would want to replace it with LINQ.

```
foreach(string attachment in email.Attachments)
     {
        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachment));
     }
```

email.Attachments is a List of String.

I have tried that:

```
  mailMessage.Attachments= email.Attachments.Aggregate(new AttachmentCollection(), (c, r) => { c.Add(new Attachment(r)); return c; });
```

But got the folowing error:

> The type 'System.Net.Mail.AttachmentCollection' has no constructors
>   defined

I'm not sure how to do it.

Any advise?

Comment: I am not clear why you are getting downvote for such question, Maybe because you didn't post any issue or errors, something that shows that you try something by yourself. So maybe give more info and what are you trying to achieve, what did you already tried, what are your issues...

Comment: Thank you for explaining me that, I really didn't understand what is wrong with my question. I will edit it as you suggested right away. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. personally I upvote for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attachments is of type AttachmentCollection. 
AttachmentCollection derived from Collection, below metdata of Collection class.

```
public class Collection<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
{
    public Collection();
    public Collection(IList<T> list);

    public T this[int index] { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; }
    protected IList<T> Items { get; }

    public void Add(T item);
    public void Clear();
    public bool Contains(T item);
    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int index);
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
    public int IndexOf(T item);
    public void Insert(int index, T item);
    public bool Remove(T item);
    public void RemoveAt(int index);
    protected virtual void ClearItems();
    protected virtual void InsertItem(int index, T item);
    protected virtual void RemoveItem(int index);
    protected virtual void SetItem(int index, T item);
}
```

You can see that Add which get one item as parameter is the only method that add item to the collection. There is no AddRange method for example which could take more than one item.
The only way to add a batch of items to the collection is through the constructor, see it get a List as parameter. But you cannot rich it using  Attachments. Attachments has only a getter, see below MailMessage metadata:

```
public class MailMessage : IDisposable
{
    public MailMessage();
    public MailMessage(string from, string to);
    public MailMessage(MailAddress from, MailAddress to);
    public MailMessage(string from, string to, string subject, string body);

    public AlternateViewCollection AlternateViews { get; }
    public AttachmentCollection Attachments { get; }
    public MailAddressCollection Bcc { get; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that's very helpful. So does it mean that it's not possible to add attachments to an email with LINQ?

Comment: Correct, this is not possible

Comment: Ok, I changed it to a for loop, this way I can easilly set the name of the attachments... Thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: @Marie, no problem, happy it helps